# Is “Any else of” idiomatic

Tags: adverbs

A group gets invited to a wedding. X, a *member* of the group, decides she’s going to go. She tells this to Z, a *friend* of the group. He asks the group who else is going. Could his question be phrased this way?

“Are/Is any else of you going to the wedding?”

If not, what’s the idiomatic way to phrase this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use "is" or "are" with "any of X"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188922/should-i-use-is-or-are-with-any-of-x)

Comment: It's certainly not idiomatic. The most usual way to say it if there is a possibility that more than one extra person might be going would be "Are any more of you going?" If the most likely number of extras is one you might say "Is anyone else going _out of your group_?" '_ out of your group' could be replaced by something more descriptive like 'from this office', 'out of this class', 'from this club' and so on but "any else" is not good English. You could say "Is anyone else going?" without mentioning the group but that could refer to all the guests, not just the group.